# Making android app that locates routers location on a map or compass

Tags: android, android-activity, wifi, modem

I am supposed to make an app that locates WiFi modems and show their location.
So far I was able to show the ssid and the distance of the routers (not accurate, but better than nothing).

So now I need to write the code that uses compass and signal level comparison to locate the direction of the modem.
The idea is that the user holds the device and slowly rotates 360 degrees while the device keeps scanning and compares signal levels. Then put a pin on the point where it got the lowest level (when the user's body is between the phone and the modem), and another pin where it got the highest level (when the device is facing the modem).
This will give 2 points, and with the distance, I should be able to put a mark on the map (or compass) that shows the modem's location.

So I need a way, or a code that does that.
Here is the code so far.
All I did is put scan results in a list.

Java file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uelp5imaup4q5f9/MainActivity.java?dl=0)  I couldn't figure out how to post it directly here.

EDIT:

so i found the compass source code [here](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html) and i was thinking if i can draw a line pointing at the direction that has the highest signal level after multiple scans, or maybe multiple lines for different modems.

Comment: Do you have the sample code of what you have tried so far?